# Play audio file in PC Java application and Android app

Tags: java, android, audio

is there a way that I can use to play audio files in both Java desktop app (CLI, GUI) and Android apps?

I know I can use javax.sound in desktop apps, but I'm not sure if this can work in Android.

Thank you!